# Enumerate with left justify after breakline

Tags: lists, environments, enumerate

I would like to change 1 thing in enumerate (or create new enviroment like enumerate)

[image]

As in picture i would like to  make "unless other switch is used" to be aligned to left (just like "Part of this text (...)")

Answer (score 3):

Use the `wide` option supplied by [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe,lipsum}% Just for this example
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\sloppy% Just for this example

\lipsum*[1]
\begin{enumerate}[wide]
  \item Lorem ipsum\ldots
  \item \lipsum*[2]
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum*[3]

\end{document}
```